# Loop through yaml collection, sort by key

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb

In an `erb`-template, I want to loop through a yaml-collection such as this:

```
collection:
  - title: "title a"
    year: 2017
  - title: "title b"
    year: 2017
  - title: "title b"
    year: 2016
  - ...
```

In the output-file (formatted as markdown), I want to order the different entries by year and split them, without knowing beforehand which `values` exist for the year-`key`:

```
# 2017
* title a  
* title b

# 2016 
* title c
…
```

Can this be achieved with an `each do`-loop in Ruby?

---

FOLLOW UP

I have a follow-up question. The solution given below works fine. Now, I want to be able to use the sort/group function achieved by this in my ERB-template. The below code outputs the desired result. But how can I call this sort/group function in the ERB template, so that entries in the "conferencecontribution" collection are ordered accordingly?

(As a side note, the YAML file also includes other collections which need to be ordered, thus it would probably make sense to make this a function?)

```
dataset = YAML.load_file('cv.de.yaml')

dataset['conferencecontributions'].group_by { |hash| hash['year'] }
      .sort_by  { |year, _| -year }
      .each do |year, entries|
  puts "# #{year}"
  entries.each do |entry|
    puts "* #{entry["title"]} #{entry["location"]}"
  end
  puts
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need multiple `group_by` and `sort_by` :

```
require 'yaml'

collection = YAML::load(%q{
collection:
  - title: "title a"
    year: 2017
  - title: "title b"
    year: 2017
  - title: "title c"
    year: 2016})["collection"]


collection.group_by { |hash| hash['year'] }
          .sort_by  { |year, _| -year }
          .each do |year, entries|
  puts "# #{year}"
  entries.map { |entry| entry['title'] }.sort.each do |title|
    puts "* #{title}"
  end
  puts
end
```

It outputs :

```
# 2017
* title a
* title b

# 2016
* title c
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine! I do have a follow-up question (see edit).

Comment: This should probably be a new question, possibly with a link to this one.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your follow-up question (which perhaps should have been posted as a separate question): Yes, you should define a method for this, such as the below:

```ruby
def by_year(data, &block)
  years = data.group_by {|hash| hash['year'] }
      .sort_by  {|year,| -year }
  block ? years.each(&block) : years
end
```

Then you would use it in your ERB like this:

```erb
<% by_year(dataset['conferencecontributions']) do |year, entries| %>
  <h1><%= year %></h1>
  <ul>
  <% entries.each do |entry| %>
    <li><%= entry["title"] %>, <%= entry["location"] %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/F3Vl